# Dependent dropdown NodeJS Express handlebars

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ajax, handlebars.js

I'm a newbie in NodeJS.

I don't know how can I do a dependent dropdown when the value changes, I know that I have to use Ajax or an event handle but I don't know how can I do it, I'm using handlebars in my view.

When I change the value from the first dropdown I want to show data in the second dropdown with the id "new_dropdown" but I don't know how can I send data to my routes file and then, receive the data for the dropdown.

This is my code for the view:

```
        <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" id="customers_dropdown">
          {{#each customers}}
          <option value="{{customer_id}}">{{customer_name}}</option>
          {{/each}}
        </select>
        <select class="form-select" id="new_dropdown">
        </select>
```

This is my code for the routes:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const pool2 = require("../database");
const { isLoggedIn, isNotLoggedIn } = require("../lib/auth");

router.get("/", isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
  const customers = await pool2.query(
    "SELECT c.id AS 'customer_id', c.name AS 'customer_name' FROM customers c WHERE c.user_id = ?",
    [req.user.id]
  );
  res.render("index", { customers });
});

router.post("/show_data", (req, res) => {

});

module.exports = router;
```

The query that I want to use to receive the data is
SELECT s.name FROM stores s WHERE s.customer_id = ?
And then, pass the value from the select box to my route and then receive the data.

I want to send data from my view and receive new data dependent on the dropdown.

Comment: I think a good first step would be to complete `/show_data` handler. You would want to implement it such that it takes a Customer ID as parameter, performs the query using the provided Customer ID (sanitized for SQL injection, of course), and then returns that query result as JSON - see: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I already did a dependent dropdown and it works :)

Comment: Should this question be closed in that case?

Comment: Yeah, that's right.